# The user name or password is incorrect-8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090579, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect AD with the following code

```
VMADProfile _VMADProfile = new VMADProfile();
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("Test AD LDAP Path", "DomainName\\username", "password");
directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(samAccountName=" + username + "))";    
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");    
SearchResult one = directorySearcher.FindOne();
```

but it is giving me following Error

```
 The user name or password is incorrect.
8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090579, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839
```

I am able to login with same user name and password if I login directly. 
My AD that I am trying to connect is different from from which i am running code. Same code works fine if i change test AD to the production AD

Comment: Error 52e means invalid credentials, i.e. password is not correct.

Comment: As I mentioned password is correct i am able to login to the server with same AD

Comment: I'm just saying what the error mean. Could you have non ascii characters in the password?

Comment: Yes I already have capital case lowercase special character and numbers

Comment: Then it could be a character set issue. Latin1 vs Unicode.

Comment: Removed the special character from password but no success

Comment: Is there any thing related to network or firewall that may cause this issue

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the key:

> My AD that I am trying to connect is different from from which i am running code.

It's probably trying to authenticate you on your domain, not the other one. Make sure your LDAP path includes the server to connect to for the other domain, and not just the distinguished name of the domain. The server name can just be the DNS name for the domain. It should look something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://otherdomain.com/DC=otherdomain,DC=com", "DomainName\\username", "password");
```

If you just use `"LDAP://DC=otherdomain,DC=com"`, it will try to connect to the domain the current computer is joined to first. That would actually work if there is a trust between the two domains, but if not, you need to specifically give it the server name to connect to.